# In A star, what is the point of recalculating the best path?

Tags: path-finding

In A* after the finding the next node with the lowest F value, you have to search the adjacent nodes again. When you find a node that was already in the open list, you're supposed to check if the g score for that node would be lower if you went through the current node to get there. My question is, what is the point of this? Won't it always be the same? If you take G = 14 for diagonal and G = 10 for horizontal/vertical wouldn't the G always be more if you went through 2 nodes instead of one?

Say the last node on the closed list's G value was 50. It has an adjacent square to the right with a G value of 60. Your current node has a G value of 64. If you went through the current node to get to the node adjacent to the one with the G value of 50, the G would be 74. You could switch the numbers all you want but the recalculated G would always be higher so what is the point of recalculating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you take G = 14 for diagonal and G = 10 for horizontal/vertical wouldn't the G always be more if you went through 2 nodes instead of one?

Yes, but that is only one specific case.  In that case, you would *not* have to check if the g-score would be lower and potentially re-add the node to the open list, because, in your graph, we can guarantee it will have the lowest g-score the first time it is added to the open list.

However, this is not true for all graphs.

---

We can formalize this.  If the heuristic we use satisfies these two constraints:

```
for all nodes x,y with an edge between them,  h(x) <= h(y) + c(x,y)  
h(goal) = 0
```

then we call the heuristic [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) *(or, less commonly, "monotone")*.  In that case, we don't need to recheck the g-scores or readd a node to the open-list.

Since your heuristic satisfies those constraints, it is consistent.

Comment: You're making a big assumption, because OP hasn't said anything about his heuristic. For all we know, it's not even admissible.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you using h? What is h in this case? If it's heuristic, why do we have to take the heuristic into a account?

Comment: @Mastrolinie: Yes it's the heuristic, and I mention it because it is the answer to your question.  Whether or not the heuristic is consistent determines whether you need to look at the g-score more than once (and possibly readd a node to the open list)

Comment: But I don't understand why we need to consider the heuristic. Aren't we only checking if the G is higher or lower? As far as I'm aware of, G is calculated independently from the heuristic.

Comment: @Mastrolinie: You stated *"When you find a node that was already in the open list, you're supposed to check if the g score for that node would be lower if you went through the current node to get there."*  I'm saying **that's only true if your heuristic is non-consistent.**  If you have a consistent-heuristic, you can skip that step.  The example you gave *(an 8-connected grid-graph where diagonal lengths = sqrt(2))* has a trivial consistent-heuristic *(the euclidean distance)*, so in that case, you are right that you can skip that step.

Comment: Could you please provide an example where the heuristic is non-consistent?

Comment: @Mastrolinie Most real-world heuristics are consistent *(which is fortunate, because inconsistent heuristics cause A\* to perform poorly)*.  [This paper](http://www.ise.bgu.ac.il/faculty/felner/newsite/publications/InconsistentHeuristics.pdf) gives an example of a contrived inconsistent heuristic.

Comment: An easy example of an non-consistent heuristic is to consider movement when you have different terrains and a complete graph on suitably placed points. `h(P) = the cost of going from P to the target` is an admissible but non-consistent heuristic.

Comment: So most of the time I'm not going to have to recalculate it if it the G of a node already on the open list would be lower had I gone through the current node to get to it, unless my heuristic is inconsistent, which rarely is the case, right?

Answer (score 0):

What BlueRaja said. Essentially A* allows you to also consider a weighted graph. Imagine that same game grid but some tiles are mountains, others are swamp and others are road. These different movement costs mean there is a faster route. For example, following the road around a mountain, rather than going over it. If the road is step cost 1, and the mountain is step cost 100. That is either a really long road, or the road is just more efficient.

Comment: But what does recalculating the cost have to do with that? Say the current node is a road and the destination point is over the mountain. The node adjacent to the top of the current node is a mountain and the mountain ends exactly where the destination is. Like in your example, there's a road going around the mountain. Using the A* algorithm, it's going to choose the road and no matter how many times it recalculates it, the road is going to stay the best option. So what exactly is the point of recalculating the G value if you went through the current node to get there?

Comment: So you are going along the road. And you are adjacent to your destination, but A road block of step cost a million is in your way. The destination is added to your open list, but may not be the shortest. You go back to the mountain and cross a few tiles. You arrive adjacent to your destination again. The cost to get to the destination is no longer a million, but only a few hundred, since you're coming from the mountain. The cost is updated.

Answer (score 0):

> In A* after the finding the next node with the lowest F value, you have to search the adjacent nodes again. When you find a node that was already in the open list, you're supposed to check if the g score for that node would be lower if you went through the current node to get there. My question is, what is the point of this? Won't it always be the same?

Only if you visit the nodes in order of increasing G value.

> If you take G = 14 for diagonal and G = 10 for horizontal/vertical wouldn't the G always be more if you went through 2 nodes instead of one?

Yes.

However, you're visiting the nodes in order of increasing F value. Depending on the details of the heuristic, this may not be the same as the order of increasing G value.

Comment: So basically you're saying that if we're checking if the F is lower had we gone through the current node to get there, It wouldn't always be the same, which I'm aware of. But if you were only comparing the G value, it would still always be higher, correct?

Comment: No, because the different between `F(P)` and `G(P)` is just `H(P)` which is assumed constant.